# Prove that $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ contains no zero divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

Trying to prove that $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ does not contain any zero divisors. So far, I have found that there are 25 elements in this quotient ring, and they all take the form of $ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

So I'm thinking proof by contradiction would be the easiest route here. Let $ax+b \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ and $ax+b$ is a zero divisor. By definition, there exists another element $cx+d \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2) -\{0\}$ such that $(ax+b)(cx+d)=0$.

$(ax+b)(cx+d)=(acx^2+bcx+adx+bd)=0$. Because $\overline{x^2+2} = \overline{0}$ we know $\overline{x}^2 = \overline{3}$. So we can plug into the equation: $(\overline{3ac}+ \overline{bd} +\overline{bc}\overline{x} + \overline{ad}\overline{x})=\overline{0}$ which simplifies to $\overline{3ac+bd} + (\overline{ad+bc})\overline{x} = \overline{0}$. For this equation to be true, the coefficient of $x$ should be $0$, so $ad+bc = 0$.

I am hoping that I will come to the conclusion that $c,d=0$ which would then create a contradiction because $cx+d \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2) -\{0\}$ so they cannot be zero. But I'm a bit stuck on how to get there, and would appreciate some help.

Also, apologies for switching to using bars above the figures and back. I'm not really sure when they are necessary or not. I'd appreciate your corrections on that.

Answer (score 5):

This is much too complicated.  Proving the quotient has no zero divisor means the ideal $(x^2+2)$ is prime, which amounts to proving it is irreducible. As it has degree $2$, it comes down to proving $x^2+2$ has no root in $\mathbf F_5$.

Now the squares in $\mathbf F_5$ are $0^2=0$, $(\pm1)^2=1$, $(\pm2)^2=-1$. Thus $-2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$.

Answer (score 1):

To finish OP's proof, transform $\overline{3ac+bd} + (\overline{ad+bc})\overline{x} = \overline{0}$ into
$$\begin{bmatrix}3a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
If $(c,d) \ne (0,0)$, there's a nontrivial solution to the above equation, so $\begin{vmatrix}3a&b\\b&a\end{vmatrix} = 3a^2-b^2 = 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$.  i.e. $3a^2=b^2$ in $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$.  Since $3$ is a quadratic non-residue $\mod 5$, this implies that $a = b = 0$.